# How to wrap an Image caching library like SDWebimageSwiftUI or Kingfisher or my own implementation in a SwiftUI project?

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, solid-principles, sdwebimageswiftui

I am working on a small SwiftUI project as I believe this is the best way of learning anything.
Coming from the background of UIKit sometime I do get confused with how to do this in SwiftUI.

**What I want to achieve and why?**

I want to render a list of `lazy loading cells containing images` and `Cache` them. Now SwiftUI provides a very clean way to do this i.e.., via `AsyncImage`. `AsyncImage` in my opinion is good for `lazy loading images` but it doesn't have any functionality to `cache` any thing.

So I have two choices either to write my own implementation of caching mechanism or use anything reliable from community and we do have `SdWebImageSwiftUI` and `Kingfisher` which will do most of the heavy lifting and are reliable enough for the result I want to achieve so I am good with any of the two libraries.

**Now what I actually want to achieve?**
I just want to `encapsulate` the usage of any of these libraries so that in future if I want to replace them with something else then I don't have to make changes everywhere in the application.
While doing so I do want to keep the functionality to add `view modifiers` to the view which we would be using.

**Eg.**

```
CachedImage(url: url_for_image)
.resizable()
.frame(width: x, height: y)
.scaleAspectFit()
.
.
.
```

The implementation which I am proposing might not be the best and I am very open to listen to the community for what can be the better way of doing this.

Please do correct me if I am wrong somewhere.